# What is the internal / native resolution of Mario Kart 8 / the Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

AKA the resolution before it was upscaled.

I'm not sure but I think the gamepad is the same resolution as the main screen.

As far as I know the resolution is 1280x720 but could this be confirmed?

And are all the game resolutions the same?

Comment: This would depend greatly on the game itself, not the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mario Kart 8 is rendered in 720p](https://www.google.com/search?q=mario+kart+8+resolution). That's 1280x720 pixel.

> Anyway, Digital Foundry makes it known that Mario Kart 8 looks quite good to be on the Wii U, and it's easy to see how some sites may have been confused and misplaced with the perception that the game was native **1080p** instead of native **720p** and upscaled to **1080p**.

---

The Wii U Gamepad does not have the same resolution. Its resolution is [854x480 pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U_GamePad).

---

Not all games have the same resolution. Some games may try to render more detailed sceneries or render at a faster framerate to appear smoother and may thus render at a lower resolution in an attempt to achieve whichever graphical goal was set.

Example: [The Legend of Zelda: The Wind Waker HD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_Waker_Wii_U) which is rendered in FullHD (1080p). That's 1920x1080 pixel.

Comment: I wonder, does Mario Kart 8 games output the same resolution to both screens?

Comment: @Hiccup, my guess is the Wii U downscales the frames before sending them to the gamepad, there is no real reason not to. The Wii U already performs H264 compression to keep bandwidth requirements between Wii U and gamepad low. The Wii U is most likely downscaling during the compression, since that would not only speed up the encoding process, but also further reduce the bandwidth requirements.